# Why if statement returning error in python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

It worked earlier, but after adding`change_balance(int(message.chat.id)` it stopped

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def answer_bot(message):
    if message.text == 'FILL BALANCE':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ваш баланс пополнен на 500 руб')
        change_balance(int(message.chat.id)
    if message.text == 'BALANCE':
        bal = show_balance(int(message.chat.id))
        print(bal)
        full_text = 'Ваш баланс: ' + str(bal) + ' руб'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, full_text)
        print('balance' + str(message.chat.id))
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
```

and it return error:

```
File "/root/Documents/Work/TG_BOT/tstbot/bot.py", line 26
if message.text == 'BALANCE':
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

PS Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing brackets in the line:

```
change_balance(int(message.chat.id)
```

a fix would be to replace it with:

```
change_balance(int(message.chat.id))
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing brackets in this line:

```
change_balance(int(message.chat.id)
```